# Android EmojiCompat: cannot resolve symbol BundledEmojiCompatConfig

Tags: android, emoji

Trying to use "Bundled fonts to use to configure EmojiCompat"

My Build tools are:

> 26.0.0

My dependency is;

```
 compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:26.1.0"
```

My Configuration lines in Application class are;

```
 EmojiCompat config = new BundledEmojiCompatConfig(this);
 EmojiCompat.init(this);
```

The issue is;

> BundledEmojiCompatConfig

is not recognized by the system although I added the imports mannually from the Android google sample

```
import android.support.text.emoji.EmojiCompat;
import android.support.text.emoji.bundled.BundledEmojiCompatConfig;
```

Comment: well, The question has nothing to do with your attached answer :), Please re-read the question

Comment: and the -1 :D, why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different Dependency libraries are provided for different use cases;

I should have used

> "com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:26.1.0"

for configuring "Bundled fonts to use to configure EmojiCompat" check [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html#bundled-fonts-supplib-dependency)